# ThreeJS load Scene exported from ThreeJS editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, three.js

I'm creating a Three.js Scene exporter from Unity3D.
As an example I use an exported scene from the Three.js Editor. But now I try to load the scene and it totally fails. I can't find any documentation or examples about that, except that I need to use the ObjectLoader.

Can somebody please give me an example on how to do that.

Comment: There have been several questions regarding this issue like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770124/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236366/. What is your specific problem?

Comment: Well it just doesn't work at all. goto http://www.firstpolygon.com/webglTest/ and all you see is a black screen.

Comment: First add bike.js script to body and try, if it works without object loader, to eliminate errors in bike.js. Because of console will not show in scripts loaded by object loader.